# How to fill the Null for duplicate records in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains snapshots for JIRA ticket status, df contains multiple snapshots for these tickets hence there are some duplications. I want to fill the null values (as long as the id has Null at one point )) in the previous snapshots with the current latest ticket status.

For instance:

```
snapshot  id  status    date
week1     111  Null     2019-10-10
week2     111  Null     2019-10-17
week3     111  Analysis 2019-10-23
```

I want to change week1 and week2's status to analysis.

Another scenario is:

```
snapshot  id  status    date
week1     111  Null     2019-10-10
week2     111  Triage   2019-10-17
week3     111  Analysis 2019-10-23
```

week2 is Triage, but the latest week3 is Analysis, df should still be changed to:

```
snapshot  id   status   date 
week1     111  Analysis 2019-10-10
week2     111  Analysis 2019-10-17
week3     111  Analysis 2019-10-23
```

Comment: You ask initially to fill Null value, but end in replacing `Triage` which is not null. Do you just want to apply last status to all rows with same id?

Comment: yes, I probably word it wrong,  I want to apply the latest status for all row with same id (as long as the id has Null at one point )

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `NaN` to all rows which don't have the `max` date, then use `backfill (bfill)` to `fillna`

```
m = df['date'].eq(df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('max'))

df['status'] = np.where(m, df['status'], np.NaN)
df['status'] = df['status'].bfill()
```

---

```
  snapshot   id    status       date
0    week1  111  Analysis 2019-10-10
1    week2  111  Analysis 2019-10-17
2    week3  111  Analysis 2019-10-23
```

**Note**
If your `date` column doesnt have datetime type yet, convert it first:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group by `id` to only select ids with a Null status, and replace all status values in those groups with the last status. Code could be:

```
for _, sub in df.groupby('id'):
    if len(sub.loc[sub['status'].str.match('Null')]) > 0:   # at least one Null in group
        dat = sub['date'].max()                             # max date in group
        status = sub.loc[sub['date']==dat, 'status'].iat[0] # last status
        if status != 'Null':                                # caution...
            df.loc[sub.index, 'status'] = status
```

This works the same if the `date` column has type string or date.